# Sonatype Nexus 3 get last updated/uploaded artifact

Tags: maven, sonatype, artifact, nexus3, maven-metadata

I have such maven-metadata.xml file content:

```
<groupId>com.ifact</groupId>
<artifactId>xxxx-exporter</artifactId>
<versioning>
<latest>0.0.21</latest>
<release>0.0.21</release>
<versions>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<version>0.0.2</version>
<version>0.0.3</version>
<version>0.0.4</version>
<version>0.0.5</version>
<version>0.0.6</version>
<version>0.0.7</version>
<version>0.0.8</version>
<version>0.0.9</version>
<version>0.0.10</version>
<version>0.0.11</version>
<version>0.0.12</version>
<version>0.0.13</version>
<version>0.0.14</version>
<version>0.0.15</version>
<version>0.0.16</version>
<version>0.0.17</version>
<version>0.0.18</version>
<version>0.0.19</version>
<version>0.0.20</version>
<version>0.0.20-1</version>
<version>0.0.20-2</version>
<version>0.0.21</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20191206104706</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

And we saw that **0.0.21** is the latest artifact version. (was created **Sun Dec 01 2019 13:28:29 GMT+0200**)

AND

**0.0.20-1** (was created **Fri Dec 06 2019 12:47:03 GMT+0200**)

**0.0.20-2** (was created **Fri Dec 06 2019 12:46:21 GMT+0200**)

So maven-metadata.xml sort files not by creation date, it sort by version.

But I need to get the last updated/uploaded artifact and I cannot rely on the contents of the maven-metadata.xml file.

I try to use API call:
`http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets?sort=&repository=xxxx-exporter-release&maven.extension=jar`

And saw a correct out:

```
  "items": [
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.21/xxxx-exporter-0.0.21.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.21/xxxx-exporter-0.0.21.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTYzMWJhOThlMDJjNTczM2Zi",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "3c775285fa2f86aabe4d7ddc42ee0a5092fa4029",
        "md5": "066e78dbfcc1dc682fdbbe0241acca5a"
      }
    },
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-2/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-2.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-2/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-2.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTYwZmQ0OWMxY2M4MDhhYjhh",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "667138ef9d6c956b38c4691f415c1aea3451f492",
        "md5": "742607e475560ef2718d8c73c9659a2a"
      }
    },
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-1/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-1.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-1/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-1.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTY4YTJmYzM3MWI5MDY2OTcz",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "7a5a77bef08f798d36a4e1eefe36d9e122690f2b",
        "md5": "77b35b49278a30141afcb3675c66c26a"
      }
    }
  ],
  "continuationToken": null
}
```

API sort them by creation time or last uploaded. But if we download an artifact that mark **latest** **0.0.21** in maven-metadata.xml. And after this make API call again
`http://127.0.0.1:8081/service/rest/v1/search/assets?sort=&repository=xxxx-exporter-release&maven.extension=jar`

At response we saw:

```
  "items": [
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTZkZDkxNWE5MWVjMTUzZDdj",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "393741a956166b3354700ec647fd1f075e86b515",
        "md5": "aeacbd02eb39da06732bfb80beb7dd64"
      }
    },
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-2/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-2.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-2/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-2.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTYwZmQ0OWMxY2M4MDhhYjhh",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "667138ef9d6c956b38c4691f415c1aea3451f492",
        "md5": "742607e475560ef2718d8c73c9659a2a"
      }
    },
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-1/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-1.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.20-1/xxxx-exporter-0.0.20-1.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTY4YTJmYzM3MWI5MDY2OTcz",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "7a5a77bef08f798d36a4e1eefe36d9e122690f2b",
        "md5": "77b35b49278a30141afcb3675c66c26a"
      }
    },
    {
      "downloadUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/xxxx-exporter-release/com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.21/xxxx-exporter-0.0.21.jar",
      "path": "com/ifact/xxxx-exporter/0.0.21/xxxx-exporter-0.0.21.jar",
      "id": "Yml6aWJveC1leHBvcnRlci1yZWxlYXNlOmExMTg4MWU5MDBiZWQyNTYzMWJhOThlMDJjNTczM2Zi",
      "repository": "xxxx-exporter-release",
      "format": "maven2",
      "checksum": {
        "sha1": "3c775285fa2f86aabe4d7ddc42ee0a5092fa4029",
        "md5": "066e78dbfcc1dc682fdbbe0241acca5a"
      }
    }
  ],
  "continuationToken": null
}
```

The last downloaded artifact becomes the latest in API response.

How can I get the last updated/uploaded artifact?

Nexus version is Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.19.1-01

Comment: Are you working on a script based on based on Build tool like Maven, Gradle etc. ?

Comment: Yes. I use maven to build .jar files

Comment: there is no date or timestamp in API response. So i confused

Comment: Why do you need the latest? If within in your pom file simply define the version you would like to consume ...